# Replace Text in multiple files

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to support android RTL and want a quick way to add support RTL in a bunch of xml 
so essentially what i want is to replace

```
android:paddingLeft = 10dp  < !-- here 10dp can be anything else -->
```

with

```
android:paddingLeft = 10dp
android:paddingStart = 10dp
```

I have seen multiple examples with grep and sed which can do text replace, but here i need to extra text to be retained and copied in the next line as well..

I am sure i can do this in notepad++ and/or write a simple java code.. but looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(android:paddingLeft(\s*=\s*\w+))/\1\nandroid:paddingStart\2/g' file
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iW6tL1) for test and explanation

Comment: Ended up doing  grep -rl android:.*Left res/ | xargs sed -i -r 's/(android:(.*)Left(\s*=\s*.*))/\1\nandroid:\2Start\3/gm'        Liked the regex101 demo, nice site !!!